# Does R follow BEDMAS - strictly?

Tags: r

Perhaps this is a ridiculous question.

Has anyone ever experienced a situation where R does not follow BEDMAS (Brackets, Exponents, Division, Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction)

Comment: Post the script that causes the problem.

Comment: Ridiculous indeed. R is not a whimsical child that might have been seen behaving naughtily. R is a program and if you think you have found a bug in the program please give us an example so that we can reproduce it too.

Comment: My question, is about the possibility, not that I've seen it happen.

Comment: See `help('Syntax')` for a complete list of operator precedence.

Comment: @Brandon: It's possible that your program will crash, not that you've seen it happen.

Comment: @0A0D, your comment was less than constructive - but thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @Henrico, thanks for pointing that out. Sometimes it's difficult to identify what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics .  The BEDMAS mnemonic isn't really a good way to think of order of operations.  Much better to just know the principles of your number field (e.g. associativity, commutativity, etc.), and remember what the shorthand is for dropping parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive answer.

Answer (score -2):

Bedmas does not apply to all math problems.  Only the higher math problems.   That is why there are two types of calculators.   Standard and Scientific.   Simple math formulas like 4*4-4*4+4-4 = is a simple math problem that doesn't require bedmas.   The order in that operation is left to right.  If the problem had brackets then you would do whatever is in the brackets first and then left to right.

Higher math like Alegbra and Calculus requires bedmas.  The more complicated the math equation.    Or if the formula was more complicated
For example:

4.25 X 43.458 - (765.3/34.3) - 25.1 =

This formula would require bedmas rules.

This is why many people get simple math equations wrong.  They apply bedmas to everything when it shouldn't be.

Comment: That's nice, but how does this apply to R?